# Recursively calculating combinations with range and sorting constraints

Tags: combinatorics

I have questions about how to extend the basic combination equations so I can compute them recursively and, at the same time, add range and sorting constraints. I am trying to do this with high school level algebra and running into a lot of difficulty. There must be a better way to think about these things.

(Side note: I'm not a mathematician or a TeX expert, so please feel free to improve on my notation and formatting. However, please don't go too far in replacing words with symbols.)

Given a sequence of variables, $(x_1,\dotsc, x_k)$, in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3051119/29642) we established that the constraint that all variables be in the range $[1..n]$ makes the number of possible sequences the number of permutations of $n$ taken $k$ at a time with replacement, which is $n^k$.

We also established that adding the requirement that $x_i \ge x_{i+1}$ changed the possible number of sequences from permutations to combinations, again with replacement: $$\binom{n+k-1}{k} = \frac{(n+k−1)!}{k!(n−1)!}$$

Now I would like some help checking my work taking it further.

### Recursion, part 1

#### Keeping the range $[1..n]$ and $x_i \ge x_{i+1}$ restrictions.

Given the number of possible sequences $C_{k-1}$ of $(x_1,\dotsc, x_{k-1})$, calculate $C_k$
$$C_k = XC_{k-1} = X\frac{(n+(k−1)-1)!}{(k-1)!(n−1)!} = \frac{(n+k−1)!}{k!(n−1)!}$$
$$X = \frac{(k-1)!(n-1)!(n+k-1)!}{(n+k-2)!k!(n-1)!}$$
$$X = \frac{(k-1)!}{k}  \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n+k-2)!}$$
$$ X = \frac{n+k-1}{k} \implies C_k = C_{k-1} \frac{n+k-1}{k} $$

Hey, that was easy! Let's try something a little harder.

### Recursion, part 2

#### Adding restriction $x_k > L$

Now we add a restriction only on $x_k$ that on top of everything else $x_k > L$ for a specific $k$ and $L$. How now do we compute $C_k$ given $C_{k-1}$ and $k$? Seems to me we just subtract the combinations in the range $[1..L]$. Let us call $S_k^n$ the set of $k$-tuples in the set before the restriction and $S_k^{n,L}$ the desired set of $k$-tuples. I'm not great with set notation, but I think it goes like this (please correct me if I'm wrong):
$$\begin{align}S_k^n & = \{(x_1,\dotsc, x_k) | x_i \in [1..n] \land x_i \ge x_{i+1} \} \\
   S_k^{n,L} & = \{(x_1,\dotsc, x_k) \in S_k^n | x_k > L \} \end{align} $$

It looks like I should just be able to subtract the $x_k \in [1..L]$ like this:

$$C_k = (C_{k-1}\frac{n+k-1}{k} - C_{k-1}\frac{L+k-1}{k}) = C_{k-1}\frac{n-L}{k}$$
**That looks wrong.** The usual lower bound on $n$ is $n > 0$ and plugging $L = 0$ into the equation gives a different answer than the usual equation. Trying a few other examples show that it is in fact, wrong. (If this *kind* of mistake is common, maybe someone can put in their answer an explanation of the class of mistakes this one falls into.)

**Trying again**, we still have $x_k \le x_{k-1}$, so the answer is less than $C_{k-1}(n-L)$, which means we cannot simply multiply our way out of it.

How many combinations are we subtracting? It is the number of combinations in $C_{k}$ where $x_{k} \le L$. Wait, isn't that what I just did? No, not quite. I did some weird recursion that did not respect what came before it. Anyway, the number to subtract is larger than  $\binom{L+k-1}{k}$ because that is only the number of combinations where *all* the variables are $\le L$. What about all the combinations where some of the variables are larger than $L$? For example
$$(5, 3, 2) \in S_3^5\text{, but } (5, 3, 2)\notin S_3^2$$

We can map all those combinations back to something that starts at 1 with $y_i = x_i - L$. That means the size of that set is the same as the one in the range $[1..(n-L)]$ Now we have 
$$|S_k^{n,L}| = \binom{n+k-1}{k} - (\binom{L+k-1}{k} + \binom{n-L+k-1}{k})$$

**That's wrong,too**, because $S_k^{n-L}$ includes tuples that map back to $x_k > L$. What we really want is $|S_{k-1}^{n-L}|$ times the $(n-L)$ copies there are. No, that's not right, either, there's only one copy where $x_{k-1} = L$, but $\binom{2}{k-1}$ copies of $x_{k-1} = 2$. This is not looking good.

**I feel like an idiot**. How did I miss that $x_i \ge x_{i+1}$ and $x_k > L$ means that $x_i > L$ for all $i \le k$?! Oh, I know, I was trying to get there from $C_{k-1}$ Anyway, now that I've circled back it is obvious that
$$ |S_k^{n,L}| = |S_k^{n-L}|$$
Still my question is, given $^nC_{k-1} = |S_{k-1}^{n}|$, is there a straightforward way to calculate $^{n-L}C_k = |S_{k-1}^{n-L}|$? Or should I just backtrack and start all over when, having computed $C_{k-1}$ I discover the $x_k > L$ restriction?